# How can I update a node with RESTful Web Services API

Tags: 7

I am able to create nodes no problem using this code but I can't seem to be able to update nodes (PUT) using the [RESTful Web Services Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/restws).  I'm pretty much am using the same code as I found on this [page](http://blog.ampli.fi/creating-drupal-7-nodes-with-php-via-the-restws-api/).

```
$crl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP script');
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/tmp/cookie.txt');

// Login.
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_URL,"//" . $site . "/user/login");
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "name=" . $user . "&pass=" . $pass . "&form_id=user_login");
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, session_name() . '=' . session_id());
$ret = new stdClass;
$ret->response = curl_exec($crl);
$ret->error = curl_error($crl);
$ret->info = curl_getinfo($crl);

// Get RESTWS token.
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://' . $site . '/restws/session/token');
$ret = new stdClass;
$ret->response = curl_exec($crl);
$ret->error = curl_error($crl);
$ret->info = curl_getinfo($crl);
$token = $ret->response;


if ($source_node_id) {
  curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_POST, FALSE);
  curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
  curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://' . $site . '/node/' . $source_node_id);
}
else {
  curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://' . $site . '/node');
}

curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, FALSE);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($node));
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'X-CSRF-Token: ' . $token));
$ret = new stdClass;
$ret->response = curl_exec($crl);
$ret->error = curl_error($crl);
$ret->info = curl_getinfo($crl);

curl_close($crl);
unset($crl);

return json_decode($ret->response);
```

Anyone have any suggestion why the node update isn't working?

Comment: What response do you get? Any errors? Did you try with an admin account?

Comment: @Ben the response is blank and no errors. I verified that restws_page_callback() never gets called but if I add .json (/node/2343.json) it does run but I will need to add a patch to handle the format in the url.